# How do I change the default value of my JQuery slider

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the default value of my slider to halfway along.

You can see at the moment it sits on the far left:

[image: image of slider]

My Jquery code snippet is as follows:

```
 $form['stepX'][$key] = array('#type' => 'fieldset', '#attributes' => array('class' => array('wb_spc_question_fieldset')));
      $form['stepX'][$key]['header'] = array('#markup' => '<div class="wb_spc_select_group_title">' . $section['name'] . '</div>');
      $form['stepX'][$key]['columns'] = array('#markup' => '<div class="wb_spc_column now">' . t('Now') . '</div><div class="wb_spc_column future">' . t('Future') . '</div>');
        $form['stepX'][$key]['values'] = array('#type' => 'fieldset');
        $form['stepX'][$key]['values'][] = array('#markup' => '<span class="wb_spc_select_span">' . $section['description'] . '</span>');

        $form['stepX'][$key]['values']['now'] =  array(
            '#type' => 'slider',
            '#animate' => 'fast',
            '#max' => 10,
            '#min' => 1,
            '#orientation' => 'horizontal',
            '#step' => 1,
            '#default_value' => empty($form_state['storage']['values']['stepX'][$key]['now']['value']) ? '4' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step'][$key]['now']['value'],
            '#slider_style' => 'orange',
            '#size' => 1,
            '#display_inputs' => FALSE,
            '#display_values' => TRUE,
            //'#display_bubble' => TRUE,
           // '#slider_length' => '100%',
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('wb_spc_select')),
          );  

        $form['stepX'][$key]['values']['future'] = array(
            '#type' => 'slider',
            '#animate' => 'fast',
            '#max' => 10,
            '#min' => 1,
            '#orientation' => 'horizontal',
            '#step' => 1,
            '#default_value' => empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step' . $step][$key]['future']['value']) ? '8' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step' . $step][$key]['future']['value'],
            '#slider_style' => 'orange',
            '#size' => 1,
            '#display_inputs' => FALSE,
            '#display_values' => TRUE,
           // '#display_bubble' => TRUE,
           // '#slider_length' => '100%',
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('wb_spc_select')),
          );  

      if(isset($section['body'])){
        $form['stepX'][] = array('#markup' => $section['body']);
      }

  }
```

This is all part of a custom Drupal module.

Many thanks.

Comment: In the $form array you can change the `'#default_value'`.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of things your solution probably lies in the line

```
'#default_value' => empty($form_state['storage']['values']['stepX'][$key]['now']['value']) ? '4' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step'][$key]['now']['value'],
```

Try changing it to:-

```
'#default_value' => '50',
```

It looks like it just empties everything by default, thus causing it to stay at 0, i could be wrong though

Comment: This K.O's everything :/ !

Comment: Oooops sorry, try `'#default_value' => 50,` i included quotations by accident

Comment: Hold up, I may have reference the wrong slider. As I've got a bunch on mysite: http://jsfiddle.net/22t1pmfp/ will update.